# Compiling OpenGL Program (Linux) - Cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl, linker-errors

I am attempting to compile a test opengl program on ubuntu. I have installed bumblebee, the nvidia 304 driver and `libgl1-mesa-dev`, using `apt-get`.

I can see the file `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` - and yet compiling with `g++` and the flag `-lGL` returns the error: `error: cannot find -lGL`.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Output of `dpkg -L libgl1-mesa-dev`

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/script
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/control
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so
```

## Update

The command `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so` gives the output:

```
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

I don't know if that's useful or correct?

Comment: Use `dpkg -L libgl1-mesa-dev` to find out what files are shipped in that package. I guess you need to use "gl" instead of "GL". If not, there are probably hundreds of examples out there for you to download and study!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Please see my edit - thanks

Comment: Well, is there a `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1`? Also, what exactly is the commandline for compiling? Further, consider extracting a minimal code example.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes - I said that in the question, that file exists. I am compiling with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g  -c /home/.../main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o` then `g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/opengl0 obj/Debug/main.o   -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU -lGL`

Comment: This is within codeblocks by the way

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: It's `-lGL` with capital `GL` as specified in the Linux Standard Base.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm confused - I am using `-lGL` with capitals?

Comment: @user3728501: it looks like the symlink `/usr/lib/libGL.so` (to `libGL.so.1` is missing on your system.

Comment: @derhass Can you explain to me how to recreate this link?

Comment: @user3728501: `sudo ln -s libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so` should do. But you shouldn't have to do this manually, and it is really unclear why this file is missing.

Comment: @derhass Yeah I agree - I went for a reinstall in the end because I figured something was badly wrong